# PC To NXT Brick via Bluetooth

Tags: bluetooth, connection, nxt, lego-mindstorms

We have a fully-working java programme which can connect to another computer and can send messages from this(both sides run java and we used ObexPutClient and ObexServer), however when trying to connect to the NXT Brick and send a message via bluetooth we are able to pair with the brick and we can send a message but we have no idea if the NXT receives it.

When we tried to use Java ObexPutClient on computer(we provide the ServerURL of NXT to java programme) to send the message to NXT Brick running the RobotC, it does't work. On java side, the error is given:

"Failed to connect; [10064] A socket operation failed because the destination host was down."
Is the error we receive on Java.

Using robotc the brick is waiting for a message to be sent and it is awaiting 3 integers to help the robot move.

How have people sucessfully done this, we have ensured the port number is the same.

Answer (score 0):

The NXT does not provide the OBEX Bluetooth service. It uses the Serial Port Profile (SPP - also sometimes called RFCOMM). When you pair your NXT with your host computer, it will create a serial port (e.g. COM4) on your host computer. In your Java program, you need to open this serial port and send data that way.

Also, [leJOS](http://www.lejos.org) has a [PC Library](http://www.lejos.org/nxt/pc/api/index.html) (Java) that includes communication and remote control features. You could probably use this so you don't have to write your own.

Comment: We've implemented the SPP but we're still getting the exact same "host was down" error. Is there any chance you could give us a few more details about how to make this work?

P.S. We'd be happy to provide code fragments if necessary.